# Join table with itself using duplicates

Tags: sql

Assume there is a table like this:

```
id  camp score flag
A2  C3   2     I
A2  C1   1     I
A1  C1   2     I
A2  C2   3     I
A1  C2   1     I
A2  C3   0     O
A1  C1   0     O
```

I want to detect all the duplicates taking just the columns `id` and `camp`. In case these pairs are duplicated, I want to keep just one row that has the `score` value when the `flag` is `I`, and then change the flag to `O`. The output should be:

```
id  camp score flag
A2  C1   1     I
A2  C2   3     I
A1  C2   1     I
A2  C3   2     O
A1  C1   2     O
```

I tried to achieve this using this query:

```
SELECT
    i.id,
    i.camp,
    i.score,
    COALESCE(o.flag, 'I') AS flag
FROM
    t1 AS i

    LEFT JOIN t1 AS o
    ON i.id= o.id AND i.camp = o.camp

WHERE
    i.flag= 'I'
    AND o.flag= 'O'
```

I thought this would work, but this returns just two rows:

```
id  camp score flag
A2  C3   2     O
A1  C1   2     O
```

Why is this happening? How can I get my desired output without creating a new table (if possible)?

Comment: Move the `o.flag= 'O'` from `WHERE` to `ON`, and see what happens.

Comment: @jarlh That seems to work, but why? I have a rather basic knowledge of SQL, but I thought that when doing a join, you had to use ```some_col = another_col```. If you can post an answer with this approach, I'll accept it as it actually solves my problem.

Comment: JOIN ON applies that criteria only to the table being joined upon. WHERE applies the criteria to the whole resultset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the `o.flag= 'O'` condition from the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause, to get true `LEFT JOIN` result. (When in WHERE, the LEFT JOIN returns regular INNER JOIN result.)

Your query modified:

```
SELECT
    i.id,
    i.camp,
    i.score,
    COALESCE(o.flag, 'I') AS flag
FROM
    t1 AS i

    LEFT JOIN t1 AS o
    ON i.id= o.id AND i.camp = o.camp
        AND o.flag= 'O'
WHERE
    i.flag= 'I'
```

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a cheat but would this work?

```
SELECT id, camp, MAX(score), MAX(flag)
FROM t1
GROUP BY id, camp
```

Comment: How do you know the max score is associated with the flag of I?

Comment: The examples show flag O being 0s, so if that isn't the case then yeah, no good

Comment: Well, yes... This works in my specific case, but it doesn't seem so robust. I mean, it's a good idea, but I'm not sure it would work in all cases.

Comment: Yes if you have flags beyond Is and Os it won't work - would need to know the other criterias. Looks like the guy who replied via comment has right idea, fix your join... but that's still limited specifically to flags of I and O in either case

Answer (score 1):

Please find an alternative answer below where temporary tables are employed to get the desired resultset. You can use "NOT EXISTS" keyword here, or to go on your own script, to get the rows you are asking for.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (id  VARCHAR(2),camp VARCHAR(2), score INT, flag VARCHAR(1))
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES 
    ('A2',  'C3',   2,     'I'),
    ('A2',  'C1',   1  ,   'I'),
    ('A1',  'C1',   2    , 'I'),
    ('A2',  'C2',   3   ,  'I'),
    ('A1',  'C2',   1   ,  'I'),
    ('A2',  'C3',   0   ,  'O'),
    ('A1',  'C1',   0  ,   'O')

SELECT m1.id,m1.camp,m1.score, flag='O'
INTO #duplicatesWithScore
FROM #temp m1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id,camp
    FROM #temp
    GROUP BY id,camp
    HAVING COUNT(*)>1
) m2 ON m1.id=m2.id AND m1.camp=m2.camp
WHERE Score>0

SELECT * 
FROM #temp t
WHERE  NOT EXISTS
(SELECT 1 FROM #duplicatesWithScore d WHERE d.id=t.id AND d.camp=t.camp)

UNION
SELECT * FROM #duplicatesWithScore
```

Answer (score 0):

You can express this logic in an aggregation query:

```
select id, camp,
       (case when count(*) = 1 then max(flag) else 'O' end) as flag,
       (case when count(*) = 1 then max(score)
             else max(case when flag = 'I' then score end)
        end) as score
from t
group by id, camp;
```